# Best way to return values from a function that writes to STDOUT

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have some helper functions that write to STDOUT for logging purposes. Some of these functions return a value to the caller, but the entire output from the function is returned.

How can I have my functions write to STDOUT *and* return a value to the caller without the return value being polluted with all the STDOUT emitted during the function call?

I'm looking for some kind of design pattern or best practise.

Consider this script:

```
Function a
{
    Write-Output "In Function a"
    $a = 4
    return $a   
}

$b = a

Write-Output "Outside function: `$b is $b"
```

The output is

`Outside function: $b is In Function a 4`

But I want the output to be:

```
In Function a
$b is 4
```

Comment: As an aside: inside PowerShell, there is technically no _stdout_ (standard output); the equivalent is the _success output stream_ - see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In PowerShell *all* non-captured output inside a function is returned, not just the argument of `return`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7):

> In PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the `return` keyword.

It doesn't matter if the function looks like this:

```
function Foo {
  'foo'
}
```

or like this:

```
function Foo {
  'foo'
  return
}
```

or like this:

```
function Foo {
  return 'foo'
}
```

it will return the string `foo` either way.

To prevent output from being returned, you can

- write to the host or one of the other [ouptput streams](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) (depending on the type of output you want to create):

  ```
  Function a {
    Write-Host 'some text'
    Write-Verbose 'verbose message'
    Write-Information 'info message'   # requires PowerShell v5 or newer
    $a = 4
    return $a
  }
  ```

  Side note: `Write-Information` is not available prior to PowerShell v5 when the [information stream](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/) was introduced, and starting with that version `Write-Host` also writes to that stream rather than directly to the host console.
- capture the output in a variable or "assign" it to `$null`:

  ```
  Function a {
    $var = Write-Output 'some text'
    $null = Write-Output 'some text'
    $a = 4
    return $a
  }
  ```
- or redirect the output to `$null`:

  ```
  Function a {
    Write-Output 'some text' | Out-Null
    Write-Output 'some text' >$null
    $a = 4
    return $a
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice; worth mentioning another way to suppress output: `$null = 'some text'`, which is typically fastest.

Answer (score 1):

another approach:

1. in your function, do logging via Write-Information.
2. in the calling scope, call the function inside a sub-expression and redirect the information stream of the sub-expression to stdout.  Be sure to assign the return value of the function to a variable, or it will also go to stdout.

eg

```
function bar() {
  Write-Information "Hello from bar()"
  return 4
}

$($x = bar) 6>&1

Write-Output "in main `$x = $x"
```

If you're on an old version of powershell and can't use `Write-Information` the same approach works with `Write-Verbose`. In that case you'd redirect as `4>&1`. With verbose you'll get the ugly yellow/black and "VERBOSE" text, unless you're redirecting the stdout of the overall script into a file, in which case the VERBOSE: tag will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to **return a 100% clean object from a method and you don't have to do any null assignments** or output anything (i.e. `Write-Information`)! The only catch is that you have to define a class. [In PowerShell 5.0 they introduced formal classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.3#static-keyword). If you have multiple methods you want to call statically without having to create an instance of the class then you can use the `static` keyword and call the methods statically and wrap them in a "UtilityMethods" class; otherwise it would make sense to create class instances.

Here is a class that defines a static method and how to call it.

```
class UtilityMethods {
        static [HashSet[int]] GetCleanHashSet(){
        $hs = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int];
        $null = $hs.Add(1);
        $null = $hs.Add(2);

        #Here is some code doing something completely unrelated to $hs. 
        #Notice how the return object and output are unnaffected by this and I don't need to do null assignments or Write-Information or anything like that.
        $hs2 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int];
        $hs2.Add(99);

        return $hs; #This will return a clean HashSet, as you would expect.
    }
}

$cleanHS = [UtilityMethods]::GetCleanHashSet();
Write-Host "cleanHS = $cleanHS" #output: cleanHS = 1 2
```

You can also add into the method whatever you want to output to the console or logging, it won't affect the return object. For me this is the best solution in most cases to write functions that will return exactly what you're expecting without piping in junk. **If you choose to use null assignments then you will have to do that on every line of code in the function that would pipe output, even if it's completely unrelated to the object you will return.**